# Load values from environment variables into Spring Cloud Config

Tags: java, spring, cloud, config, environment

As a test, I added `test.me: ${TEST_ME}` to `application.properties`. I curl down and that value shows up as expected in my generated properties file.

I expect that adding the TEST_ME value to the server where Spring Cloud Config is running should overwrite this value and show up in my curl command.

So far, this hasn't been the case. Is it possible?

Comment: Is the application connecting to the Config server? What is the application name, which Spring profiles is the application actively using and what is the file name where you defined TEST_ME that should be available via the Spring Config server?

Comment: Yes, the application is connecting fine and pulling its configuration. I defined TEST_ME in application.properties so that it gets distributed to all configurations.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.
1) What's the name of the application reading the properties from the Config server?
2) Which Spring profiles is the application from 1) using?
3) What is the file name where you defined TEST_ME that should be available via the Spring Config server?
If you defined TEST_ME in Config server's application.properties, that is not how it is supposed to work. Properties defined in Config server's application or bootstrap.properties are for internal use, not to expose them to client apps

Comment: My blog at http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/09/Centralized-and-Versioned-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-and-Git.html covers setting up Config server and client app, demo source code available.

Comment: ```If you defined TEST_ME in Config server's application.properties, that is not how it is supposed to work. Properties defined in Config server's application or bootstrap.properties are for internal use, not to expose them to client apps``` Thanks that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Oh, well.